# Create subarraylist with condition

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections, sublist

i have a problem to get `SubarrayLists`.
I have a Class `Accgy`. Its including 4 Cells of an Excelsheet (Cell y,x,z ,acc).

```
    public class Accgy {

        Cell y;
        Cell x;
        Cell z;
        Cell acc;

        public Accgy(Cell x, Cell y, Cell z, Cell acc) {
            this.y = y;
            this.x = x;
            this.z = z;
            this.acc = acc;
        }

        Cell getCellz() { return z; }
        Cell getCelly() { return y; }
        Cell getCellx() { return x; }
        Cell getCellacc() { return acc; }

    }
```

In the Excelsheet A x,y and z are one Row. In the ArrayList `accgy` there are all values of the Excelsheet

I have values from an another Excelsheet B in the Arraylist `maxPerRange`.
In this Arraylist there are only the highest values of the Excelsheet B.
Both Excelsheets have the same number of Rows.

I want to create an Arraylist which do subArraylists of the ArrayList `accgy`with the start of index 1590 and end `accgy.size()-700`. But with the condition that if the values of the ArrayList `accgy`and `rowIndex` and the values of the ArrayList`maxPerRange` the`rowIndex`are the same, it should divide the ArrayList in subArrayLists.

I want in the subArraylist all values of the ArrayList `accgy` between the `rowIndex` of `maxPerRange`. So the `rowIndex`  of `maxPerRange` should be like borders.
The values in the subArraylist should be from one `maxPerRange` till the next `maxPerRange`.

I hope it was clear the explain my problem.

Here is the Code what i have till now.

I think one mistake is `partitions1.add(accgy.subList(i, accgy.size() - 700));`

But i am not sure. I hope someone can help me.

```
        List<List<Accgy>> partitions1 = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 1590; i < accgy.size() - 700; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < maxPerRange.size(); j++) {
                if (accgy.get(i).getCellx().getRowIndex() == maxPerRange.get(j).getRowIndex()) {
                    partitions1.add(accgy.subList(i, accgy.size() - 700));
                }
            }
        }

        for (List<Accgy> c : partitions1) {
            for (Accgy g : c) {
                System.out.println(g.getCellx().getNumericCellValue());
                System.out.println(g.getCellx().getRowIndex());

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed my Problem. With this code i have the same numbers of subarrayLists like the size of the ArrayList `maxPerRange` and the values of the ArrayList `maxPerRange` are the borders when it should do a subarrayList.

```
    List<List<Accgy>> partitions1 = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1590; i < accgy.size()-700; i++) {
                for (int j=0;j< maxPerRange.size();j++) {
                    if (accgy.get(i).getCellx().getRowIndex() == maxPerRange.get(j).getRowIndex()) {
                        partitions1.add(accgy.subList(i,  maxPerRange.get(j+1).getRowIndex()));
                    }else if(accgy.get(i).getCellx().getRowIndex() >= maxPerRange.get(maxPerRange.size()-1).getRowIndex()){
                            break;
                        }

                }
        }
```

I hope it helps for someone who has the same problem.